# Web API with OWIN Auth is returning "Authorization has been denied for this request." on every action with [Authorize]

Tags: .net, api, token, owin

I have Web API with taken based authorization. I am successfully able to register a user and get `access_token` from the API. But, when I post to any other endpoint with  the `access_token` on the header for the same user, I am getting

> "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."

If I remove the `[Authorize]` decoration on the action method,  only the client is validated in the `ValidateClientAuthentication` and request gets processed fine.  I am trying to post these requests from Postman, sending body parameters as `x-www-form-urencoded`.

[image]

The API is built using `oAut`h and MS identity. Client gets authenticated successfully in `ValidateClientAuthentication`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add Bearer before your token on the access_token parameter
It should look like this :

Authorization: Bearer sdifusdifnPOIJDFPIUdfhpiuhdfg164

Answer (score 0):

Suffixing Bearer to the access token with a space in between in Authorization key of the request header worked for me.

Authorization : "Bearer Access_Key"

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In token authentication (also called Bearer authentication ) in OWIN.
The **bearer token** is a cryptic string, usually generated by the server in response to a login request. The client must send this token in the Authorization header when making requests to protected resources. **So we need to pass bearer as a prefix with the token.**

Example: bearer aGM_wMX8ngpe5ZglJwOASwnDfq1Pf4CtUrGgtOVFOvJA-tf0sckHNG9iUpI-7fWZFWE5uDb_OT3taasAxcUQnZCWxpm6mRhyg9pRjJwcVjXtJdSupaZ1bKhTYKI2fNCVqfM6Iosoyx2ziD7Qm7dRQj-cMe